# How to use slack-api pins.add method

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I am trying to use `pins.add` method , documentation says they now don't support file, file_comment, but there is no specification on how send text that i want to pin.

I have tried using slack client as mentioned below, but it says not_pinnable and if i don't mention text it says `no_item_specified`.

```
sc.api_call("pins.add", channel=channel_id, ts=x, file='test', file_comment='helo')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pinning a text you need to reference the message that you want to pin, which already needs to exist in a channel. You can reference a message by providing channel ID and the timestamp of the message.

You get the timestamp of a message when you post it yourself (its in the response from the API) or from a message event or by fetching all messages from a channel with `conversations.history`.

Example:

```
sc.api_call("pins.add", channel=channel_id, timestamp=message_timestamp)
```